# Excel 365 open listbox when click cell, make selections then hide listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm just starting to learn VBA and am trying to figure out how to add a list box that would pop up when a user clicks any one of a certain group of merged cells (identified by a named range). The list values would come from a named range in a separate tab. The user would make their selections (multiselect) which would populate in the merged cell they originally clicked and then the list box would close when they are finished. The user would need to be able to remove previous selections and/or add new ones as these values change sometimes.

I tried the VBA provided in this page but it doesn't have a remove option.
https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-listbox.html.

I'm currently using code that allows you to choose values one-by-one from a  Data Validation list but it's cumbersome having to do it one-by-one.

[merged cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9q9G.png) - these are an example of the merged cells. The named range is "Recur". The default value is always  recurrence but the user would change this value to any of the following when first creating the document:
[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhjsR.png) - named range "Recurrence"

I would expect when the user first creates this document that they would click on one of the cells labeled  and a listbox would pop up allowing them to choose the appropriate values which would replace  (e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd). The listbox would then be hidden when they're finished making their selections. Then say 6 months later it's now 1st, 2nd, 4th so they click that same cell with the 1st, 2nd, 3rd in it, the listbox pops up and they remove 3rd and add 4th but 1st and 2nd stay.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This code will handle what you want to do.  You can seelct items one-by-one from a Data Validation drop-down list, and they'll be added to the cell.  To remove any item, select it again.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const SEP As String = ","
    Dim c As Range, NewValue As String, OldValue As String, arr, v, lst, removed As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub '<< only handling single-cell changes

    'add some code to restrict ranges, if needed
    '...
    Set c = Target
    
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Not c.Validation Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewValue = c.Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = c.Value

        If OldValue = "" Then
            c.Value = NewValue
        Else
            arr = Split(OldValue, SEP)
            'loop over previous list, removing newvalue if found
            For Each v In arr
                If Trim(CStr(v)) = NewValue Then
                    removed = True
                Else
                    lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & v
                End If
            Next v
            'add the new value if we didn't just remove it
            If Not removed Then lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & NewValue
            c.Value = lst
        End If
    End If    'has validation and non-empty
    
Exitsub:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** OK here is an alternative approach using a UserForm.

In the worksheet code module for where you want the selections to be made:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    'some example code to check the clicked cell is one we want to handle
    Set lo = Me.ListObjects("contacts")
    Select Case True
        Case Not Application.Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Roles").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing
            Cancel = True         'don't enter edit mode
            ShowPickList Target   'show picklist form
    End Select
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Sub ShowPickList(c As Range)
    Dim frm As frmPickList
    Set frm = New frmPickList
    Set frm.SourceCell = c
    frm.PickList = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Lists").ListObjects("MyList").DataBodyRange.Value
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

The userform `frmPickList` has OK and Cancel buttons.  Form code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const THE_SEP As String = "|"

Private m_cell As Range
Private m_list As Variant '2D array from Range.Value


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim r As Long, arrCurr As Variant, currVal As String
    Dim cb As MSForms.CheckBox, v, i As Long, hadCellValue As Boolean
    
    currVal = Trim(m_cell.Value)
    If Len(currVal) > 0 Then
        'make an array with all values currently in the cell
        arrCurr = Split(currVal, THE_SEP)
        For i = LBound(arrCurr) To UBound(arrCurr)
            arrCurr(i) = Trim(arrCurr(i))
        Next i
        hadCellValue = True
    End If
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(m_list, 1)
        v = m_list(r, 1)
        With Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "ChkBox" & r)
            .Top = 15 * r
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 300
            .Caption = v
            'check if this value is already in the cell
            If hadCellValue Then
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, arrCurr, 0)) Then
                    .Value = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next r
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim con As Object, s As String, sep As String
    For Each con In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(con) = "CheckBox" Then 'is a checkbox?
            If con.Value Then              'checked?
                s = s & sep & con.Caption  'add to list for cell
                sep = " " & THE_SEP & " "  'populate separator after first value
            End If
        End If
    Next con
    m_cell.Value = s  'populate the cell
    Unload Me
End Sub

Public Property Set SourceCell(c As Range)
    Set m_cell = c
End Property

Public Property Let PickList(lst As Variant)
    m_list = lst
End Property
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, i should've mentioned that this is what I'm currently using but I want the ability to make the selections all at once rather than having to do it one by one. i'll edit my post.